# How to remove child by id and retrive the parent objects using filter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter the parent, by removing it's child id only by not matching. in case if there is no child exist, the parent should be removed.

I try like this, but not works.

```
var rm = 7;

var objects = [
  {
    name: "parent1",
    id: 1,
    blog: [
      {
        name: "child1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "child2",
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent2",
    id: 2,
    blog: [
      {
        name: "child3",
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: "child4",
        id: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent3",
    id: 3,
    blog: [
      {
        name: "child5",
        id: 5
      },
      {
        name: "child6",
        id: 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent4",
    id: 3,
    blog: [
      {
        name: "child6",
        id: 7
      }

    ]
  },
]


var result = objects.filter(value => {
    if(!value.blog) return;
  return value.blog.some(blog => blog.id !== rm)
})

console.log(result);
```

What is wrong here, or some one show me the correct approach?

looking for :

1. need to remove the blog if the id is same as rm, parent with other children required to exist.
2. need to remove the parent, after remove the children, in case there is no child(blog) exist.

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p6vohrdb/1/)

Comment: In case of having multiple children, and having one of the ids matching rm, you want to keep the rest of them, is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. if there is no children, the parent not required at all, In case we remove the last children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the list of parents, and inside that loop, try to remove blogs with the given id first. Once you have done that, you can check if the blogs property has became empty, and if so, filter it out:

```
// We're going to filter out objects with no blogs
var result = objects.filter(value => {
  // First filter blogs that match the given id
  value.blog = value.blog.filter(blog => blog.id !== rm);
  // Then, if the new length is different than 0, keep the parent
  return value.blog.length;
})
```

Comment: It looks cleaner than mine

Answer (score 2):

I think the below code is what you are looking for

```
var result = objects.map(value => {
   const blog = value.blog.filter(blog => blog.id !== rm);
   if(blog.length === 0) {
        return;
   }
   value.blog = blog;
   return value;
}).filter(item => item);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lp82z4k/3/

Comment: when we remove the blog with id 7, still the parent exists.

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole object or only the blog key?

Comment: want to remove whole object, if there is no blog.

Comment: yes, removed. but why the length or array still as 4 ?

Comment: No it's 3 @3gwebtrain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191629/discussion-between-pedram-marandi-and-3gwebtrain).

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = objects.map(parent => {
parent.blog = parent.blog.filter(child => child.id !== rm);
return parent}).filter(parent => parent.blog && parent.blog.length > 0);
```